# Nuxt prerendered static site doesn't work with google translate, content gets rerendered

Tags: nuxt.js

I've made a simple website and i am trying to use google to translate the complete site, using the google translate webpage.

I see google will translate the page content, then the page rerenders with the original english text.

Is this a known issue? Is the rerendering preventable?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please show us some debugging material here.

Comment: Also, what is the end goal with the Google Translate thing?

Comment: This is my first nuxt site, i've noticed a lot of live websites on the web have the same issue.
It happens on a clean install with just a simple text page as well.
The goal is simply offering a translated version of the website.

Comment: I'm still not sure of what you're trying nor what you want to achieve. Looking at this website, you can see that this is properly translated: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=auto&tl=zh-TW&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tediber.com%2F

Comment: The issue occurs with me when i use npm run generate.
When i go to the site when it's running on port 3000 i can use google translate.
But when i go to the generated version in /dist folder, it will reload after the translation happened.

example: https://nuxt.kremersfroon.site

The last one of the generated javascript files that is called seems to have the original content in it, and will replace the translated content, it seems.

Comment: I really do not understand what is the goal of Google Translate here. Neither I do understand what is to be seen on the website that you've linked. Nor I do see any issues. Can you please elaborate with a more in-depth example, some code or a [repro]? Here, it's really cryptic to even understand what you're expecting from Google Translate. And...where the bug is. You can even link a video if you want.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=en&tl=zh-TW&u=https%3A%2F%2Fnuxt.kremersfroon.site%2F

This should be now visible in chinese, yet for me it isn't.

It is a fresh nuxt install, with generated static site using the command "npm run generate"

Comment: Let me know if you ever figure this out. Apparently this can work: https://dev.to/coolgoose/quick-hack-for-using-google-translate-or-other-services-in-nuxtvuejs-3gb2 but I've never tried it.

There might be some packages that could help.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch I think the solution you linked is for when using a plugin

Comment: @kissu in your example the javascript isn't loaded, i suspect that is why it is working on that site.

Comment: Apparently nuxt is lacking the functionality to work with a service like google translate. That's a shame.
You could have just said that instead of being vague @kissu